# Sporadically receiving 502 bad gateway error with Spotify Web API

Tags: spotify

Sometimes, while calling the `https://api.spotify.com/v1/me` endpoint, I receive a 502 bad gateway error. This error occurs sporadically.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Code:

```
PublicProfile profile = null;

var url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me";
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", TokenType + " " + AccessToken);
    var response = wc.DownloadString(url);
    profile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PublicProfile>(response, settings);
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you calling the API? Do you have any code?

Comment: according the docs you should also receive a json paylod with an error message https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/user-guide/

Comment: The content of payload is: Bad gateway.

Answer (score 1):

I having the same issue. A majority of time when I make this request I get the 502: Bad Gateway response. Occasionally I will get an actual response. I am using Python and rauth library to make this request, this leads me to believe this is an error on Spotify's end and not ours.